# SQL Proc results not the same as SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, union

I have a select statement made up of 4 unions and returns 18000+ rows which is correct. each bring back 5000, 5000, 5000 and 3000.

I have now added this to a proc using a UNION ALL/ UNION as this is a data set for an SSRS report.

But when I run this as a whole my results for that part of the query brings back a lot less rows, the results that show 3000 rows is only showing as 40.

can anybody help and shed some light on what can cause this issue as this is giving false figures on my report.

Comment: Can you provide the code you used (statement and procedure)?

Comment: Select LEADSOURCEID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT as LEADSOURCEID, LEADSOURCE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT As Leadsource, Username, 
CASE WHEN USERNAME = 'Blackburn' THEN 'Power4Business'
     WHEN USERNAME LIKE 'SDU%' THEN 'Energy Search'
  WHEN USERNAME LIKE 'DUAL' THEN 'Commercial Reduction Services'
  End as Brokername,
  Leaddate, ' ' as UTILITY_TYPE, 'Imported' as Misc, ID 
FROM

Comment: Edit the question. Don't add comment with code. This is totally unreadable.

Comment: Take into account that `UNION` makes `DISTINCT`. Run stored procedure with parameters from SSRS report to check if you got propper result.

Comment: Click the "Edit" link under your question (above) and add the code from your query, the code from your stored procedure, and an example of your unexpected results.

Comment: Try following this SO guide to proving [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Without more information it's very hard to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First:

`UNION` makes `DISTINCT` so you can lost rows in that part.

Second:

Try to run stored procedure with the same parameters which you are using inside the report to see if you have propper result.

Third:

If stored procedure returns propper result check your reports design.

Comment: I'm using the same date parameters on both stored procedure and report .

Comment: Report is matching the result in the stored procedure but that is where the rows are being lost.

Comment: I told you the steps that can be done to try to fix your issue. I don't see your procedure and I don't have design of your report. I just give you guidance how to try to manage problem yourself. Edit the question to provide more details. It sound like: I have report and stored procedure but they don't work! How to fix them.